# Use split environment within align environment using multiple ampersands

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, numbering

I was trying to use the align environment to align multiple equations on one line as described here:

https://latex.wikia.org/wiki/Align_(environment)

My code is simply:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a &= b  &  c &= d  &  e &= f \\
b &= a  &  d &= c  &  f &= e
\end{split}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

This works well and produces the desired output, except that there is a different equation number for each line.

I tried to remove multiple equation numbers with split, as I would do if there was only one ampersand. The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a &= b  &  c &= d  &  e &= f \\
b &= a  &  d &= c  &  f &= e
\end{split}
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

However, this causes the error:

```
l.12 \end{align}
                
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate
```

Why doesn't split work in that mode (multiple ampersands per line)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `aligned` instead, split only supports one `&` per row. Which is why my goto is always `aligned`, then `split` can be used in those few cases were it is relevant.